# How to go next page by XPath?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, paging

I'm trying to scrape reviews from a cosmetics brand site, and can not go on to the next pages.

It's like:
1|2|3|...|10|(next button)
and if you click the next button, you can see the pages like
11|12|13|...|20|(next button).

I did scraping of the pages 1~10 by using this code:

```
nextpage = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='num']/a[text()='" +"10"+"']")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", nextpage)
```

but can not do further work over the page 10.
This is the HTML of the site:

```
<div class="paging">
<span class="prev2">...</span>
<span class="num">...</span>
...
<span class="num>
   <a href="javascript:goPage('9');">9</a>
</span>
<span class="num on">
   <a href="javascript:void(0);">10</a>
 </span>
<span class="next">
   <a href="javascript:goPage('11');">
      <em class="hide">다음</em>  # 다음 means next in Korean
   </a>
</span>
```

Thank you. It will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "but can not do the further  work", mean nothing. You get an error? You don't get the output you want? Please add details.

Comment: Do you have any updates? Did you try my answer? Thanks.

Comment: Hi! Any updates?

Answer (score 0):

Please try below solution:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "div[@class="paging"]//span[@class="next"]/a"))).click();
```